# Change process name and publisher name of a VB application in windows

Tags: windows, forms, process

I am writing a VB forms application. The exe file created shows the name of the project in the task manager. I want a different name as the process name, process description and a custom name for the publisher name. I am using Visual studio 2013. How do I do that?

Comment: I think you do this by changing the `Assembly name` property within the project window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the project settings.
Under your project name in solution explorer-> find "My Project" as a wrench icon.

Opening this will open the project settings.
Set the Assembly name and root namespace to the desired names.
Set the title to the name you want to see in the Task Manager.
The company name should be that of the Publisher name in Task Manager.

Now make a copy of the exe file and give the desired name. You should be good to go!